# Открытие дополнительной вкладки и обновление страницы нажатием на ссылку

Tags: html, javascript

Доброго всем времени суток господа

Я попытаюсь объяснить максимально понятно, т.к. гугль меня не понял. Представьте себе вы в браузере нажимаете по ссылке правой кнопкой мыши и - открыть в фоновой вкладке. В итоге страница на которую ведет ссылка открывается в новой вкладке, а вы остаетесь на прежней.

Можно ли сделать такую ссылку (со скриптом JS или без него) при нажатии на которую текущая страница изменялась на нужную мне, и я оставался на ней, и открывалась новая вкладка, так же с нужной мне страницей?

p.s. если эта конструкция имеет какое то название прошу подсказать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Я попытаюсь объяснить максимально
> понятно

Я максимально ничего не понял но может что-то вроде

```
<a href="http://google.com" rel="http://yandex.ua">Откроем две ПС сразу</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

    for(var i in a)
    {
        a[i].onclick = function()
        {
            if(this.getAttribute('rel') != null)
            {
                window.open(this.getAttribute('rel'));
                window.location.href = this.getAttribute('href');
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                window.location.href = this.getAttribute('href');
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Если атрибут rel задан и имеет ссылку то в новом окне откроется тот адрес который там записан, текущее окно пойдет по адресу который записан в атрибут href.

Comment: Классно. получилось http://google.com - это ссылка 1, http://yandex.ua - это ссылка 2. При нажатии перешел на окно со ссылкой 2. А можно ли остаться в текущей вкладке? т.е. там, где была ссылка 1?

Comment: Это специфика браузера, в Опере все именно так и происходит.

Comment: ну можно и так, хотя я вопрос подругому понял)

Answer (score 2):

ну в яве это видимо

```
window.open("http://mylink.net", "windowName");
```

в чистом html

```
<a href="http://mylink.net" target="windowName">new window link</a>
```

а откроется это в новой вкладке или в новом окне зависит от браузера и как он настроен. поумолчанию на такие ссылки обычно отрывается в новой вкладке.

Comment: эмм.. я так понял при использовании этого произойдет переход по одной ссылке. я же спросил про 2 (одна в новой вкладке, другая в текущей)

Comment: тааак, делаем акцент на `target` в теге `а`... не будет перехода ;) вот если в аттрибуте `target` указать `_self`, который является значением поумолчанию для этого аттрибута, то будет перезод по ссылке в текущем окне, а так будет открыто новое окно, к которому можно будет обратиться по его имени, заданному в `target` :)  
 
так же для яваскрипта, не путайте window.open и window.location. Последний перейдет по ссылке в текущем окне, первый откроет новое окно/вкладку